# Unzip files in loop

Tags: linux, compression

I have the following code which extracts numbers from netcdf files and every loop puts them in another netcdf file.

```
mapfile Latitude < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt) #tr is transform from to -s is squeeze. So look in the text files for all the spaces and replace them by newline '/n'
mapfile Longitude < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLongitude.txt)

echo "length of Lat is ${#Latitude[@]}"
echo "length of Lon is ${#Longitude[@]}"

outputNumber="$(ls -lq *_??????.nc | wc -l)"

echo "the number of output netcdf fles is ${outputNumber}"

valueI=`cat I.txt`
valueJ=`cat J.txt`
arrI=($valueI)
arrJ=($valueJ)

for ((i=1; i<=outputNumber; i++)) 
do
        echo "geknoei$i.nc"
        ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,${arrJ[i]},${arrJ[i+1]} -d ni_u,${arrI[i]},${arrI[i+1]} -v vel_u *_??????.nc gekneoi$i.nc 

done
```

Due to space issues, I had to compress the input files and this code no longer works. I was wondering if I could make a code which in a loop decompresses a file (one at a time) extracts what I need and then recompresses it at the end of the loop.

So something along the lines of this:

```
mapfile Latitude < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt) #tr is transform from to -s is search. So look in the text files for all the spaces and replace them by newline '/n'
    mapfile Longitude < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLongitude.txt)

echo "length of Lat is ${#Latitude[@]}"
echo "length of Lon is ${#Longitude[@]}"

outputNumber="$(ls -lq *_??????.nc | wc -l)"

echo "the number of output netcdf fles is ${outputNumber}"

valueI=`cat I.txt`
valueJ=`cat J.txt`
arrI=($valueI)
arrJ=($valueJ)

for ((i=1; i<=outputNumber; i++)) 
do
        echo "geknoei$i.nc"
        gunzip *_??????.nc.gz
        ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,${arrJ[i]},${arrJ[i+1]} -d ni_u,${arrI[i]},${arrI[i+1]} -v vel_u *_??????.nc gekneoi$i.nc
        gzip *_??????.nc 

done
```

The problem is that this uncompresses all the files at once, which will take up to much space. If I unzip one file at a time, my ncrcat code won't work anymore, since it extracts from all available -unzipped- .nc files.

How do I uncompress one .nc file at a time while still making the line `ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,${arrJ[i]},${arrJ[i+1]} -d ni_u,${arrI[i]},${arrI[i+1]} -v vel_u *_??????.nc gekneoi$i.nc` work?

Comment: consider one of the fuse file-systems, to mount the zip-file as a directory. Then you can access it, and it is decompress just in time.

Comment: Just commenting: `tr -s` is not for "search", it's for "squeeze", as in "squeeze consecutive newlines into single newlines".